# Trouble using multiple attribute for file upload in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, file, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using the following tag in jquery mobile

```
<input type="file" multiple />
```

But it does not lead to select multiple files in mobile

Do I need to change anything?

Thank You

Comment: You need to add a name attribute to the input at least

Comment: i also gave the name attribute but still it does not work in andriod

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this

```
<input name="upfile[]" type="file"  multiple="multiple" >
```

But as i have just burned though 5-6 hours into making this work. I can say that Multi upload still don't work in Mobile Browsers. Specially Android, though they are somewhat functional in iPhone but still not smooth.

To confirm this i tried to upload file on facebook via mobile browsers and it's broken there as well for android users. But for iPhone it upload one by one.

Your best bet it to use single file upload multi time using Ajax. it's still not very reliable on android but works good on iphone.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does not work in my android phone emulator.